# How to pass a file content to the description key using parameters for Jenkins Pipeline scripts?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I would like to pass a file content to the description key, mainly because the description that I have is very huge and would be easier to modify the file than the description

```
parameters {

    string (
      name: 'SOME_NAME',
      defaultValue: '',
      description: 'SOME_DESCRIPTION'
    )
}
```

I have not idea if this is possible on Jenkins, any help here will be welcome!

Comment: Try using """ instead of '
`parameters {

    string (
      name: 'SOME_NAME',
      defaultValue: '',
      description: """SOME_DESCRIPTION"""
    )
}`

Comment: Thanks I know but it is not the case, really I have a big huge file that I wonder to handle in a separarte file

Comment: there was an issue with file upload in jenkins. I'm using this solution for that: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413?focusedCommentId=366085&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-366085
and after upload you can evaluate pipeline from string

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will apply this WA and will see how it works